# IOS Objective-C Xcode 8.3 Url decoding issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9

I'm trying to decode the URL string in Objective-c Xcode 8.3.
Here is my URL string

> [http://www.ios=multiPointShow?sourceApplication=from_wb&dev=0&q=32.269951%2C119.177404%2Chotel+168%E9%85%92%E5%BA%97%2C%E5%A4%A7%E5%BA%86%E8%B7%AF200%E5%8F%B7%28%E8%A7%A3%E6%94%BE%E8%A5%BF%E8%B7%AF%E4%B8%8E%E5%A4%A7%E5%BA%86%E5%8C%97%E8%B7%AF%E4%BA%A4%E6%B1%87%E5%8F%A3%29%2CB02020JATI%2C&title=Hotel+168%E9%85%92%E5%BA%97&android=androidamap?action=shorturl&p=B02020JATI,32.269951,119.177404,Hotel+168酒店,大庆路200号(解放西路与大庆北路交汇口)&sourceApplication=from_wb&wp=multiPointShow?sourceApplication=from_wb&dev=0&q=32.269951%2C119.177404%2Chotel+168%E9%85%92%E5%BA%97%2C%E5%A4%A7%E5%BA%86%E8%B7%AF200%E5%8F%B7%28%E8%A7%A3%E6%94%BE%E8%A5%BF%E8%B7%AF%E4%B8%8E%E5%A4%A7%E5%BA%86%E5%8C%97%E8%B7%AF%E4%BA%A4%E6%B1%87%E5%8F%A3%29%2CB02020JATI%2C&title=Hotel+168%E9%85%92%E5%BA%97&mo=http://m.amap.com/?p=B02020JATI,32.269951,119.177404,Hotel+168酒店,大庆路200号(解放西路与大庆北路交汇口)&callapp=0&src=app_share](http://www.ios=multiPointShow?sourceApplication=from_wb&dev=0&q=32.269951%2C119.177404%2Chotel+168%E9%85%92%E5%BA%97%2C%E5%A4%A7%E5%BA%86%E8%B7%AF200%E5%8F%B7%28%E8%A7%A3%E6%94%BE%E8%A5%BF%E8%B7%AF%E4%B8%8E%E5%A4%A7%E5%BA%86%E5%8C%97%E8%B7%AF%E4%BA%A4%E6%B1%87%E5%8F%A3%29%2CB02020JATI%2C&title=Hotel+168%E9%85%92%E5%BA%97&android=androidamap?action=shorturl&p=B02020JATI,32.269951,119.177404,Hotel+168%E9%85%92%E5%BA%97,%E5%A4%A7%E5%BA%86%E8%B7%AF200%E5%8F%B7(%E8%A7%A3%E6%94%BE%E8%A5%BF%E8%B7%AF%E4%B8%8E%E5%A4%A7%E5%BA%86%E5%8C%97%E8%B7%AF%E4%BA%A4%E6%B1%87%E5%8F%A3)&sourceApplication=from_wb&wp=multiPointShow?sourceApplication=from_wb&dev=0&q=32.269951%2C119.177404%2Chotel+168%E9%85%92%E5%BA%97%2C%E5%A4%A7%E5%BA%86%E8%B7%AF200%E5%8F%B7%28%E8%A7%A3%E6%94%BE%E8%A5%BF%E8%B7%AF%E4%B8%8E%E5%A4%A7%E5%BA%86%E5%8C%97%E8%B7%AF%E4%BA%A4%E6%B1%87%E5%8F%A3%29%2CB02020JATI%2C&title=Hotel+168%E9%85%92%E5%BA%97&mo=http://m.amap.com/?p=B02020JATI,32.269951,119.177404,Hotel+168%E9%85%92%E5%BA%97,%E5%A4%A7%E5%BA%86%E8%B7%AF200%E5%8F%B7(%E8%A7%A3%E6%94%BE%E8%A5%BF%E8%B7%AF%E4%B8%8E%E5%A4%A7%E5%BA%86%E5%8C%97%E8%B7%AF%E4%BA%A4%E6%B1%87%E5%8F%A3)&callapp=0&src=app_share)

When I am trying the same URL on the below website its working fine
[https://www.url-encode-decode.com/](http://UrlDecodeWeb)

But I'm not getting the decoded format as the web. You can see the image below. Url decoded properly and showing q=32.269951,119.177404

But in Objective-C, I'm not getting the same result.

It is showing like q=32.270073%2C119.177359

```
 NSString *str =  [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"S: %@",str);

str =  [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"S: %@",str);

str =  [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLUserAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"S: %@",str);

str =  [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"S: %@",str);

str =  [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"S: %@",str);

str =  [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"S: %@",str);

str =  [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"S: %@",str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you are calling is used to *add* percent escapes to a string, not remove them. Instead, you need to use:

```
NSString *str = [string stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
```